# Response redirect to aspx page that does exist gets 404 error even in VS2012 debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0

I have an existing website that has many redirects and has been working fine. I recently made substantial change to one of the aspx.vb codebehind pages and now when I try to redirect to that page, I get a 404 error, even when debugging when I F11 single step from the response.redirect call.

The page exists. it is in the same location as before. I assume the 404 is due to something I changed in the code behind but I would think I could at least step into the Page_Load but even though I have a break point set on the Page_Load, I am still getting the 404 when I try to redirect and it doesn't hit the Page_Load.

The path for the redirect, when viewed in the debugger before pressing F11, is the correct path.

I am using .NET Framework 4, VB.Net, VS2012

Any ideas?

Comment: You're using source code control right? Undo the changes until you get it to a working point, then figure out what you did that caused it to break.

Comment: can you share some of your code specific to the redirect?

Comment: By reverting from source control and single stepping each change, I located the problem. Part of the changes made involved using some TrueTypreFont objects in some PDF generation code. The *.ttf files referenced were installed on the computer but were not specifically added to the project itself. I was surprised that I couldn't get any more detailed debugging information except the website 404 page while debugging in Visual Studio. No Stack trace to reference a code line that was causing the problem. Anyway, thanks for your help, mason. How do I give you credit for this answer?